# Does de Rham's theorem hold for non-paracompact manifolds?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

> For every smooth $2$nd-countable manifold $M$ and non-negative integer $p$, the de Rham homomorphism
> $$\mathcal{I}:H^p_{dR}(M)\to\operatorname{Hom}(H_p(M),\Bbb R),\quad\mathcal{I}[\omega][c]=\int_{\widetilde{c}}\omega,$$
> where $\widetilde{c}$ is a smooth representative of the class $[c]$, is an isomorphism.

This is a typical statement of de Rham's theorem, taken from Lee's "Intro to Smooth Manifolds". Since a general paracompact manifold (i.e. one that isn't required to be $2$nd-countable) is a disjoint union of $2$nd-countable manifolds (its components) and a disjoint union of de Rham manifolds (i.e. ones for which the theorem holds) is de Rham, I figure the theorem should hold for all paracompact manifolds as well. Now what I'm wondering is, are there any examples of **non-paracompact** manifolds for which the theorem also holds?